# phantomjs not setting the correct DesiredCapabilities for the executable file path

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to set the path for my executable phantomjs.exe in the DesiredCapabilities object for the webDriver. However it is adding an additional path to the one specified. I guess its taking it from my system but how to prevent it from doing it.The code is given below:

```
  DesiredCapabilities DesireCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
DesireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\Users\su.t\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64\bin\phantomjs");
        System.out.println(DesireCaps.getCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY));
                WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(DesireCaps);
```

This is throwing the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: `**/home/niti.j/**C:\Users\su.t\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64\bin\phantomjs`

**The one seen in bold is getting added automatically to the path specified.**
Please let me know how to prevent this
PhantomjsDriver version:1.2.1

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
     <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
<artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be some issue with the path specified. Double check the path and path should be the folder containing the drivers not the driver itself.

so 
In this location of yours : 
C:\Users\su.t\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64\bin\phantomjs

phantomjs should be your folder which contains the phantomjs driver. If this phantomjs is inside bin folder make your path:
C:\Users\su.t\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64\bin

Comment: thanks for the reply, changing the path is not helping , its still adding /home/niti.j/  to the path  automatically. I want to prevent this from happening

Comment: @Nitika Jain Are you using this code to run in remote server or putting in repository and running in server.? If that is the case have your drivers in the server